# I am wondering what is wrong with my begin() for my custom vector implementation. It tells me "redefinition of vector as a special symbol

Tags: c++, vector

I am getting a redefinition of begin error on my custom vector class implementation.

I tried calling iterator begin in my function headers. (see code below for more info.

```
#ifndef DSVECTOR_H
#define DSVECTOR_H

template <class T>
class DSVector{
public:
    typedef T* iterator;
    DSVector();
    DSVector(int mysize);
    DSVector(int mysize, const T & initial);
    DSVector(const DSVector<T> &V);
    DSVector& operator=(const DSVector<T> &V);
    iterator begin;
    iterator end;
private:
    int size;
    int capacity;
    T* Buffer;

};

template <class T>
DSVector<T>::DSVector(){
     size = 0;
     capacity = 10;
     Buffer = 0;
}

 template<class T>
DSVector<T>::DSVector(int mysize){
    size = mysize;
    this->capacity = capacity;
    Buffer = new T[size];
}

template<class T>
DSVector<T>::DSVector(int mysize, const T & initial){
    size = mysize;
    capacity = mysize;
    Buffer = new T[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < mysize; i++){
        Buffer[i] = initial;
        //T();
   }
}

template<class T>
DSVector<T>&DSVector<T>::operator=(const DSVector<T> &V){
    delete [] Buffer;
    size = V.size;
    capacity = V.capacity;
    Buffer = new T[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    Buffer[i] = V.Buffer[i];
    }
   return *this;
}

template<class T>
typename DSVector<T>::iterator DSVector<T>::begin(){

}
```

I am not expecting the redefinition error, but I can't figure out how to make it go away

Comment: In the class you declare a variable `begin` but later try to redefine it as a function.  This is because you left the `()` out of the declaration in the class `iterator begin();` (same for `end`).

Comment: BTW, your `operator=` is flawed and buggy in so many ways.  It will fail on self-assignment, it will fail horribly if `new[]` throws an exception due to the object being corrupted.  You should implement the copy constructor first, and then the assignment operator becomes a simple set of `swap` calls.

Comment: yep 1201ProgramAlarm I realized that after I posted this question lol.

Comment: Also this line seems buggy: `this->capacity = capacity`